# Switching from Karma to Chutzpah, can't interpret base

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, fixtures, chutzpah

I'm in the process of switching from Karma to Chutzpah and got all my tests executing fine, except when it comes to interpret jasmine's fixturepath, in Chutzpah, I'm getting "Fixture could not be loaded". It seems as if Chutzpah is unaware of what to do with the "base" portion of the url

```
it('Get all filtered', function () {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "base/site/js/apps/mock-json-data/";
    var response = readFixtures("all.json");
    makes = JSON.parse(response);
    expect(makes).toBeDefined();
});
```

Is there a configuration in Chutzpah that could tell it to interpret "base"? We could replace it, but don't want to force all developers to move from Karma to Chutzpah, which will just be used for CI

Comment: Can you share your chutzpah.json file contents?

Comment: Thanks @MatthewManela. We ended up resolving the issue. I'll post the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution, but we ended up overriding the readFixtures function to replace the "base" in the url pattern expected by Karma as follows:

```
var rf = readFixtures;
var readFixtures = function (path) {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath =
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath.replace(
            'base/site/js/apps', '../'
        ); // makes the path relative for Chutzpah
    return rf(path);
};
```